# Securing spring boot application Microservices

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

Objective : To create a Microservice which acts as a security-manager for all other Microservices

What i have acheived is, a microservice with a sample java configuration,

```
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http    .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**", "/index").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/tryadmin").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/try").hasRole("USER")
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint)
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .successHandler(loginSuccessHandler)
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .enableSessionUrlRewriting(true)
                .maximumSessions(1);
}
```

But the antMatchers are looking for a rest service within the application context. i.e, It is looking for a rest service inside the security-manager Microservice.

But what i want to do is, I want to authenticate and authorize the request, i dont want to call the service inside the application context as the antMatcher do. Instead I want a 200 ok response after authentication and authorization.